# Converting TAB Delimited to CSV

Tags: php, csv, converters, export-to-csv

I'm currently opening a TAB delimited file with the following code...

```
if (($handle = fopen($filetxt, "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    // var_dump($data);
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<br>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

Now I'm just trying to figure out how I can put the data into a CSV using fputcsv. An example would be great -- right now I'm just trying to get the headers into a CSV and then I can go from there.

The data right now (that's being echoed) looked like this...

```
part_number
aaia_part_term_id
short_description
bullet_points
list_price
jobber_price
base_price
epc_code
length
width
height
weight
image_name
```

If I could just figure out how to echo only the header into the CSV, I think I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fopen only gives you a handle to the file. A csv file's formatting relies going through each line, the way you are reading the file uses all contents at once, try:

```
<?PHP

if($handle = fopen($filetext, "r") !== FALSE){

 while (!feof($handle)) {
  $line_of_text = fgets($handle);
  foreach( fgetcsv($line_of_text, 0, "\t") as $csv_item)
   print $csv_item."," ;
  print "<br>";
 }

 fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

I haven't tested this

Answer (score 0):

Since a CSV file is just a comma delimited data file, it might be simpler just to read the current tab-delimited file line by line, and replace tabs with commas

```
if (($handle = @fopen($filetxt, "r")) !== false) {
  while (($line = fgets($handle, 0)) !== false) {
    $csv_line = str_replace("\t", ",", $line);
    // write $csv_line to your csv file
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```